# java files missing from my war files while deploying

Tags: java, jsf-2, tomcat7, war, web-deployment

I created the war file of my java web project(using jsf in Glassfish and Netbeans IDE) and tried to deploy it on tomcat7 server but i got "HTTP Status 404 - /webapplication1/" error. I tried to extract the files but i could not see any option for it to unzip. However from my IDE I can see the files contained in that war.The war contents are only .xhtml and some config but the java classes are missing. Now can anyone be kind enough to tell me if the war should contain those class files or not and also solution if possible what should i do to make my war deployable in tomcat server?
I dont have good idea about war files.

Comment: Read server startup log for clues.

Comment: what is the error that you see in tomcat logs?

Comment: If I'd do an educated guess, it's a `ClassNotFoundException` on `FacesServlet` which is causing the whole deployment to fail. This is in turn rather self-explaining and googlable. Hint: Tomcat isn't a Java EE container, it's a barebones JSP/Servlet container which doesn't provide JSF out the box.

Comment: @BlausC thanks BlausC. Can you please let me know how can i deploy that JSF (war file)project into the tomcat?

Comment: Thank you BlausC. You were right  there is ClassNotFoundException for which i googled but could not find the solution. It is trying to find the file which is not in the WAR as i have mentioned earlier. What should i do now???PLEASE DO answer

Comment: BalusC is always right.